# Reusable async await network call to return different groups of data

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency

I am letting users create "booklists" and I'm storing the Google Books ID for the specific book they added in firestore. When they go to their profile to see what books they've added, I run a fetch request to recreate all of those books in their list.

Previously, I was using completion handlers to run multiple network requests but after some feedback, I'm trying to restructure the function to use async/await to make sure everything is done before completing. I think I have successfully built the reusable function in my book service, but now I'm struggling to actually use it. I have four groups of books being returned - current, next, finished, and sharing. I've tried adding them all as tasks on the view but that seemed inefficient to me. I've also tried using my old structure to call the functions again from the ListsViewModel but I get tons of errors (which is the way it is in the following code). Thank you!

**BookService**

```
class BookService {
    
    //MARK: REUSABLE FETCH BOOK FUNCTION
    
    func fetchBooks(uid: String, document: String) async throws -> [Book] {
        
        let bookIds = try await fetchBookIdsFromFirebase(uid: uid, document: document)
        
        print("got bookIds in to fetchbooks func")
        
        let books = try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Book.self, returning: [Book].self) { group in
            
            for bookId in bookIds {
                
                group.addTask {
                    try await self.decodeBook(bookId: bookId)
                }
                
            }
            
            var books = [Book]()
            
            for try await result in group {
                books.append(result)
            }
            
            return books
        }
        
        return books
    }
    
    func decodeBook(bookId: String) async throws -> Book {
        
        guard let url = try await createListURLs(for: bookId) else { throw SearchError.badUrl }
        
        print("got to create url in fetchbooks func")
        
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else { throw SearchError.badResponse  }
        
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(Book.self, from: data)
    }
    
    func fetchBookIdsFromFirebase(uid: String, document: String) async throws -> [String] {
        
        let snapshot = try await COLLECTION_BOOKLIST.document(uid).collection(document)
            .getDocuments()
        
        let documents = snapshot.documents
        
        let bookIds = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: String.self) })
        
        print("got bookIds from firebase : \(bookIds)")
        
        return bookIds
    }
    
    func createListURLs(for bookId: String) async throws -> URL? {
        let baseURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/\(bookId)"
        
        let components = URLComponents(string: baseURL)
        return components?.url
    }
}
```

**ListsViewModel**

```
class ListsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var user: User
    
    @Published var users = [User]()
    @Published var currentBooks: [Book] = []
    @Published var nextBooks: [Book] = []
    @Published var doneBooks: [Book] = []
    @Published var sharingBooks: [Book] = []
    @Published var book: Book?

    let bookservice = BookService()
    let service = UserService()
        
    init(user: User) {
        self.user = user
        fetchCurrent()
        fetchNextUp()
        fetchDone()
        fetchSharing()
    }
    
    func lists(forFilter filter: Lists) -> [Book] {
        switch filter {
        case .current:
            return currentBooks
        case .next:
            return nextBooks
        case .done:
            return doneBooks
        case .sharing:
            return sharingBooks
        }
    }
    
    func fetchLists(forFilter filter: Lists) -> () {
        switch filter {
        case .current:
            return self.fetchCurrent()
        case .next:
            return self.fetchNextUp()
        case .done:
            return self.fetchDone()
        case .sharing:
            return self.fetchSharing()
        }
    }
    
    func fetchCurrent() {
        guard let uid = user.id else { return }
        do {
            currentBooks = try await bookservice.fetchBooks(uid: uid, document: "current")
        } catch {
            return currentBooks
        }
    }
    
    func fetchNextUp() {
        guard let uid = user.id else { return }
        do {
            nextBooks = try await bookservice.fetchBooks(uid: uid, document: "next-up")
        } catch {
            return nextBooks
        }
    }
    
    func fetchDone() {        
        guard let uid = user.id else { return }
        do {
            doneBooks = try await bookservice.fetchBooks(uid: uid, document: "done")
        } catch {
            return doneBooks
        }

    }
    
    func fetchSharing() {
        guard let uid = user.id else { return }
        // old way of using function
        bookservice.fetch2(forUid: uid, document: "sharing") { books in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.sharingBooks = books
            }
        }
    }
```

**BookListView**

```
struct BookListView: View {
    @Binding var selectedList: Lists
    @StateObject var viewModel: ListsViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(viewModel.lists(forFilter: self.selectedList)) { book in
            
            NavigationLink {
                LazyView(BookPageView(viewModel: BookPageViewModel(book: book)))
            } label: {
                ListItemBookWithButton(book: book, selectedList: $selectedList, viewModel: viewModel)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Book Model**

```
struct ApiResponse: Codable {
    var items: [Book]
    let error: ApiError?
    let timestamp: Timestamp?
}

struct Book: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String?
    let selfLink: String?
    var volumeInfo: VolumeInfo
    var timestamp: Timestamp?
}

struct VolumeInfo: Codable {
    var title: String
    let authors: [String]?
    let categories: [String]?
    let description: String?
    let industryIdentifier: [IndustryIdentifier]?
    let imageLinks: ImageLinks?
}

struct ImageLinks: Codable {
    let thumbnail: URL?
}

struct IndustryIdentifier: Codable {
    let type: String
    let identifier: String
}

struct ErrorMessage: Codable {
    let domain: String
    let message: String
    let reason: String
    let location: String
    let locationType: String
}

struct ApiError: Error, Codable {
    let code: Int
    let message: String
    let errors: [ErrorMessage]
}
```

**MainListView**

```
struct MainListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ListsViewModel
    
    private let twoItems = [GridItem(spacing: 8), GridItem(spacing: 8)]
    private let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2
    
    @State var image = Image("book-empty-1")
    @State var selectedList: Lists = .current
    @State var rotate: [Int] = [-6, 0, 6]
    @State var offset: [Int] = [2, 8, 16]
    @State var offsettwo: [Int] = [-4, 2, 10]
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: twoItems) {
            ForEach(viewModel.isSharingListUser ? Lists.allCases : Lists.filteredList, id: \.rawValue) { item in
                NavigationLink {
                    LazyView(BookListView(viewModel: viewModel))
                } label: {
                    VStack (alignment: .center) {
                        
                        Text(item.title)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                            .font(Font.body)
                            .padding(.top, 8)
                        
                        if viewModel.lists(forFilter: item).isEmpty {
                            EmptyImages
                        } else {
                            
                            HStack (spacing: -15) {
                                ForEach(Array(zip(viewModel.lists(forFilter: item).prefix(3))), id: \.0) { index, book in
                                    AsyncImage(url: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks?.thumbnail) { phase in
                                        if let image = phase.image {
                                            image
                                                .resizable()
                                                .scaledToFit()
                                                .frame(width: 64, height: 93)
                                                .cornerRadius(6)
                                                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(rotate[index])))
                                                .offset(y: CGFloat(offset[index]))
                                        } else {
                                            Image("empty-book")
                                                .resizable()
                                                .scaledToFit()
                                                .frame(width: 64, height: 93)
                                                .cornerRadius(6)
                                                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(rotate[index])))
                                                .offset(y: CGFloat(offset[index]))
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: 175, maxHeight: height)
                    .clipped()
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                            .stroke(Color(.systemGray5), lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                    .padding(.top)
                    .padding(1)
                }
                .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
                    self.selectedList = item
                })
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}

extension MainListView {
    var EmptyImages: some View {
        HStack (spacing: -15) {
            ForEach(0...2, id: \.self) { index in
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 64, height: 93)
                    .cornerRadius(6)
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(rotate[index])))
                    .offset(y: CGFloat(offsettwo[index]))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

code for linking :

```
@MainActor
class ListsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var user: User
    
    @Published var selectedBooks: [Book] = []
    
    @Published var selectedList: Lists = .current
    
    @Published var users = [User]()
    @Published var sharedUsers = [User]()
    @Published var shareListCount: Int = 0
    @Published var currentBooks: [Book] = []
    @Published var nextBooks: [Book] = []
    @Published var doneBooks: [Book] = []
    @Published var sharingBooks: [Book] = []
    @Published var book: Book?
    
    @Published var state: ListsStates = .loading
    
    @Published var isListsCompleted = false
    @Published var isShareCompleted = false
    @Published var isSharedUsersCompleted = false
    
    private var currentFetchTask: Task<Void, Error>?
    
    let bookservice = BookService()
    let service = UserService()
    
    enum ListsStates {
        case loading
        case loaded
        case empty
    }
    
    var isSharingListUser: Bool { return user.isCurrentUser == true || user.isSharedWithMe == true }
    
    init(user: User) {
        self.user = user
        identifySelected()
    }
    
    
    func fetch(forFilter filter: Lists) {
        guard let uid = user.id else { return }
        
        self.selectedBooks = []
        currentFetchTask?.cancel()
        
        currentFetchTask = Task {
            self.selectedBooks = try await bookservice.fetchBooks(uid: uid,
                                                          document: filter.document)
        }
    }
    
    func identifySelected() {
        if selectedList == .current {
            selectedBooks = currentBooks
        } else if selectedList == .next {
            selectedBooks = nextBooks
        } else if selectedList == .done {
            selectedBooks = doneBooks
        } else if selectedList == .sharing {
            selectedBooks = sharingBooks
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This all looks pretty solid. I haven't code-reviewed every line, but nothing seems amiss. (You've come a really long way from your last attempt; this seems nice code overall. You've learned very quickly.) "I've tried adding them all as tasks on the view but that seemed inefficient to me." That doesn't sound inefficient to me. Swift Concurrency can easily handle hundreds of tasks. They're not free, but they're not very expensive compared to a network call. Can you explain a little bit more about your concern?

Comment: Hmm... now I see the problem. Your ListsViewModel doesn't look quite right. It should have a single `@Published` property that is the proper list to display, and the View should just display it. Does that make sense? (I'll write up a full answer in a moment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly fine as a starting point. An important change you should make, however, is to drive the View directly from the ViewModel. What I mean is that there should be a single `@Published` property that always represents the books to display. A simple implementation might look like this:

```
enum Lists: String {
    case current, next = "next-up", done, sharing
}

@MainActor
class ListsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var user: User
    
    @Published var books: [Book] = []

    let bookservice = BookService()

    private var currentFetchTask: Task<Void, Error>?
    
    init(user: User) {
        self.user = user
    }

    func fetch(forFilter filter: Lists) {
        guard let uid = user.id else { return }
        self.books = [] 
        currentFetchTask?.cancel()
        currentFetchTask = Task {
            self.books = try await bookservice.fetchBooks(uid: uid, 
                                                          document: filter.rawValue)
        }
}
```

Then the View would always just display the current value of `books`, no matter what it is:

```
ForEach(viewModel.books) { book in
```

This isn't a complete answer. You need to think about what happens when there are errors, or the fetch is interrupted. Currently this just clears the list while it's being changed, but you might want something else. And you may want to move `selectedList` into the view model, so that it's easier to synchronize. But this should be a good starting point.

---

Your latest code is quite close IMO. It just can benefit from some minor cleanup:

Don't make selectedList `@Published`. This is something other objects modify, not something other objects watch. And put a `didSet` on it to update `selectedBooks`:

```
var selectedList: Lists = .current {
    didSet {
        selectedBooks = selectedBooks(for: selectedList)
    }
}
```

And then create a method to get the right books. This uses the new "switch is a value" feature from the latest Swift. If you are using an older Swift, you can just add `return` to each leg.

```
func selectedBooks(for list: Lists) -> [Book] {
    return switch list {
    case .current: currentBooks
    case .next: nextBooks
    case .sharing: sharingBooks
    case .done: doneBooks
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a mainlistview where I display a preview of the books by list before clicking into the booklistview. I'm struggling to use this implementation in a way that lets me fetch all of the lists back to back.. any idea how i could do that?

Comment: It's fine to create an `@Published` property for each thing you need to observe, as you did originally. Just create another one for the "selected" list, and assign to it whenever the selected list changes. The key is that a View should always observe the same `@Published` properties. It shouldn't try to reconfigure itself. If what it needs to display changes, the view model should update the thing it is observing.

Comment: I can't figure out the best way to assign the "selectedBooks" property to whatever list book property I need (ex. "currentBooks", "nextBooks", etc.) I added code above to show how I'm currently doing it but it feels wrong.

Comment: Edited. I think you're on the right path. It only feels wrong I suspect because the code is a little messy due to the `if`. Switching to a `switch` cleans it up.